# How do I work with Ipad Safari on this example codepen? (it looks like a nightmare)

Tags: javascript, ios, css, ipad, safari

I've been doing the exercises in Freecodecamp and I'm now messing around with stuff in the personal portfolio exercise, just trying out different features. My sample portfolio website looks okay in most desktop browsers, and I have an idea on how to fix the mobile android/kindle fire versions with some media queries.

However, I tested the codepen site on an Ipad Safari and the results made me want to throw my ipad out the window. It doesn't even show any html content and literally nothing works - it's an absolute abomination.

Can anyone give me some hints as to just what is going wrong in the Safari mobile browser compared to every other browser? It's so messed up that I'm not really sure just where to start...

Codepen: https://codepen.io/hsinwang5/pen/yOpZag

An example image (It's way too big...): [image: Way too big]

The offending css:

```
  html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  width: 50vw;
  margin-left: 23.7vw;
  height: 4em;
  top: 0em;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.scroll-up {
  top: -40em;
  transition: top 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

.nav {
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: .4em;
  font-family: covered by your grace, sans serif;
}

nav a {
  margin-left: 1em;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: green;
}

#hero {
  margin-top: -20px;
  /*image taken from topwallpapers.pw*/
  background-image: url("http://i1053.photobucket.com/albums/s462/HsinWang5/dark_animals_grayscale_lions_black_background_lion_profile_desktop_1900x1200_hd-wallpaper-733464_zpsuczcstcl.jpg");
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 25vh;
}

h1, h4 {
  color: gray;
  font-family: chewy, sans serif;
}

.main-content {
  /*image taken from topwallpapers.pw*/
  background-image: url("http://i1053.photobucket.com/albums/s462/HsinWang5/CroppedLion_zpsbk5znhxr.jpg");
  margin-top: -20px;
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: chewy, sans serif;
  color: yellow;
}

.static {
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.main-content p {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.main-content h2 {
  font-size: 3.7em;
  padding-top: 1%;
}

#portfolio {
  margin-top: 30vh;
}

.project {
  margin-bottom: 80vh;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  width: 350px;
  color: green;
}

.project h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

#end-portfolio {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 65vh;
}

footer {
  background-image: url("http://i1053.photobucket.com/albums/s462/HsinWang5/lion_lion_cub_family_cub_caring_baby_sunshine_40132_1920x1080_zpsae93h3zy.jpg");
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
  margin-top: -20px;
  height: 100vh;
}

footer h3 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding-top: 5vh;
}
```

Comment: I admire your passion. Thought it is not clear what is the problem with iPads? maybe a screenshot would demonstrate this more clearly.

Comment: The entire hero screen gets blown up to massive proportions, and it simply stops scrolling at the end of the hero section, so everything below the hero section simply gets cut off. Kinda seems like its interpreting "100VH 100VW" as meaning a 60" big-screen TV.

Comment: Hmm.. try adding the viewport meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` codepen allows you to add this from the HTML settings modal

Comment: Hmmm...I tried this, and now the site looks manageable under debug view, but it's still completely messed up in editor/details/full page view. I might get pro and test out the live view and see what I get. I'll try to post a screenie.

Comment: Personally, I would test this on a development server and not rely on codepen and all their possible site specific bugs coming through on your content. I tested the site on my iPad and it certainly wasn't working properly. Id link your live site, much easier to debug.

Comment: The site doesn't have a live version unfortunately - I'm still just at a "student" level so this was made purely for a freecodecamp activity. However, I did try codepen's cross-browser testing and it works decently on the mac version of Safari. The debug mode also works (The scroll events don't work - but I think I can work around that) It seems to be messed up only on the iPad. I have read that Safari interprets VH and VW differently so I'll try to fiddle with some units and see what happens. If all else fails I'll just come back to it once I'm more experienced, I suppose.

Comment: Yo ya made my day with this description about throwin stuff out tha window and that absolutely state of art screenshot :D +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for anyone who's running into the same problem. I've narrowed down that the problem only seems to happen in Safari for iOS while running on codepen. Seems like codepen runs your website in an i-frame, and mobile Safari gets really weird when using VH and VW units in frames.

Using debug view fixes this problem, so this was basically more of a codepen problem rather than a problem with the CSS. Debug view basically cuts out the codepen bloat and just runs the pure code - the only kicker is that only the account owner can use debug view.

[This page](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2014/09/24/fixing-cross-browser-issues-with-css3-viewport-units-in-ie9-and-safari-for-ios/) contains great info explaining the problem, and even provides code to fix the issue of i-frames. I haven't confirmed that it works however, because I no longer have access to the ipad in question (was borrowed from a friend).

I've also confirmed that most mobile browsers don't support fixed backgrounds or constant scroll-events, so those issues are expected.